# How to use xpcall with a function which has parameters?

Tags: lua

On [this website](http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=xpcall) there is an example on how to use xpcall on a function without parameters. But how can i use xpcall on a function like this:

```
function add (a, b)
  return a + b
end
```

And it should get the return value.
This is my attempt (does not work, i get: false, error in error handling, 
nil):

```
function f (a,b)
  return a + b
end

function err (x)
  print ("err called", x)
  return "oh no!"
end

status, err, ret = xpcall (f, 1,2, err)

print (status)
print (err)
print (ret)
```

Comment: Rolled back to remove answer from question for reasons explained by @EtanReisner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using Lua 5.1 then I believe you need to wrap your desired function call in another function (that takes no arguments) and use that in the call to `xpcall`.

```
local function f (a,b)
  return a + b
end

local function err (x)
  print ("err called", x)
  return "oh no!"
end

local function pcallfun()
    return f(1,2)
end

status, ret = xpcall (pcallfun, err)

print (status)
print (ret)
```

In Lua [5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-xpcall) and [5.3](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-xpcall) `xpcall` now accepts function arguments directly:

> `xpcall (f, msgh [, arg1, ···])`
>
> This function is similar to `pcall`, except that it sets a new message handler `msgh`.

So the call would be:

```
status, ret = xpcall (f, err, 1, 2)
```

in your sample code.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I also post an alternative solution on my main post in a sec.

Comment: Also note that LuaJIT, despite supporting 5.1, also allows you to pass arguments via xpcall.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Your "alternate" solution is what I pointed out in the 5.2 and 5.3 section of my answer. And you shouldn't put answers in your post. If you answer your own question then add an answer to your question. That's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Your answer had no example. If i add an answer to my question then i can't format the code in the answer.

Comment: I didn't think I needed a literal code example given the snippet of example in the manual and the clearly applicable concept there (you almost had it in your test snippet for example).

Comment: You can always ask for one if you don't understand what the manual is saying. But that's not the point. The point is my answer covered it and even if it didn' you shouldn't edit it into your post. You should add your own answer.

Comment: I ofc understanded it, but provided an extra code example for others who don't... i don't know why you are so angry about another helpfull example, this site exists to help others, but i think most people only help to get points...

Comment: I'm not angry. Nothing in my response was at all angry. I was confused and wanted to make sure you'd understood that my answer had covered the solution you listed as "alternate" (in case you hadn't understood that). I also wanted to explain to you how one goes about correctly answering a question that they themselves has asked (by posting an answer not by updating the question).

Answer (score 4):

```
function f (a,b)
  return a + b
end

status, ret = xpcall (f, debug.traceback, 1, 5)

print (status)
print (ret)
```